# SWIG wrappers and deleted default constructors

Tags: c++, go, swig

I am trying to build a Go SWIG wrapper for E57Format, the C++ library for E57 files (see https://github.com/asmaloney/libE57Format). Go can't compile the wrapper because it needs default constructors for some classes in which the default constructor is deleted.

In E57Format.h, pick the `e57::Node::parent()` function (line 179):

```cpp
class Node
{
public:
    Node() = delete;

    NodeType    type() const;
    bool        isRoot() const;
    Node        parent() const;
```

The generated C wrapper is:

```cpp
e57::Node *_wrap_Node_parent_libe57format_c463bf06275b76de(e57::Node *_swig_go_0) {
  e57::Node *arg1 = (e57::Node *) 0 ;
  e57::Node result;
  e57::Node *_swig_go_result;

  arg1 = *(e57::Node **)&_swig_go_0; 

  result = ((e57::Node const *)arg1)->parent();
  *(e57::Node **)&_swig_go_result = new e57::Node(result); 
  return _swig_go_result;
}
```

Note the line
    `e57::Node result;`

This line is not compilable, since `e57::Node` default constructor is deleted.

I tried many things:

- ignoring functions that fail, buy I really need some of them
- the `%nodefaultctor` directive, but it noes not avoid using default costructors, it prevent the generation of wrappers of default constructors.

This is my current swigcxx file

```
%module libe57format

%include "stdint.i"
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_vector.i"

namespace std {
    typedef signed char     int8_t;
    typedef short int       int16_t;
    typedef int         int32_t;
    typedef long int        int64_t;
    typedef unsigned char       uint8_t;
    typedef unsigned short int  uint16_t;
    typedef unsigned int        uint32_t;
    typedef unsigned long int   uint64_t;
}

//Things that do not work:
%nodefaultctor e57::Node;
%ignore e57::Node::Node();
%ignore e57::Node::destImageFile() const;
//%ignore e57::Node::parent() const;
%ignore e57::Node::operator ==(e57::Node) const;
%ignore e57::Node::__equals__(e57::Node) const;
%ignore e57::Node::operator !=(e57::Node) const;
%ignore e57::Node::__notEquals__(e57::Node) const;
%ignore e57::StructureNode::StructureNode(ImageFile);
%ignore e57::StructureNode::destImageFile() const;
%ignore e57::StructureNode::parent() const;
//%ignore e57::StructureNode::get(const ustring&) const;
//%ignore e57::StructureNode::get(int64_t) const;
%ignore e57::StructureNode::operator Node() const;
%ignore e57::VectorNode::VectorNode(ImageFile);
%ignore e57::VectorNode::VectorNode(ImageFile, bool);
%ignore e57::VectorNode::destImageFile() const;
%ignore e57::VectorNode::parent() const;
%ignore e57::VectorNode::append(Node);
%ignore e57::VectorNode::get(const ustring&) const;
//%ignore e57::VectorNode::get(int64_t) const;
%ignore e57::VectorNode::operator Node() const;

//%ignore e57::SourceDestBuffer::SourceDestBuffer;

%{
#include </usr/local/include/E57Format/E57Format.h>
%}

%template(SDBVector) std::vector<e57::SourceDestBuffer>;


%ignore e57::BlobNode;
%ignore e57::ScaledIntegerNode;
%ignore e57::CompressedVectorWriter;

%rename(__type__) e57::Node::type;
%rename(__equals__) e57::Node::operator==;
%rename(__notEquals__) e57::Node::operator!=;
%rename(__equals__) e57::ImageFile::operator==;
%rename(__notEquals__) e57::ImageFile::operator!=;
%rename(__Node__) e57::StructureNode::operator Node;
%rename(__Node__) e57::VectorNode::operator Node;
%rename(__Node__) e57::CompressedVectorNode::operator Node;
%rename(__Node__) e57::IntegerNode::operator Node;
%rename(__Node__) e57::ScaledIntegerNode::operator Node;
%rename(__Node__) e57::FloatNode::operator Node;
%rename(__Node__) e57::StringNode::operator Node;
%rename(__Node__) e57::BlobNode::operator Node;

%include </usr/local/include/E57Format/E57Format.h>
```

I'd like to generate wrappers that C++ can compile, possibly without writing C code myself (not writing C code is the reason for which I'm using Go).

Thank-you.